# How can I declare a SFML window to all my class functions?

Tags: c++, class, sfml, variable-declaration

This might be a noob question, but I'm trying to make a simple player move in a 2D-grid in SFML. I'm creating a while  loop for rendering what is happening, and I can get it to work, but I want to use classes for the grid and players etc. The problem is that when I create a window called 'window', I don't know how to implement classes since these don't know what the 'window' is. I hope I have described my problem sufficiently, and I would like any respons on how to make this work or if my method of doing it is already bad and should be changed for another method. Here is a snippet of my code for the class and the undeclared window error.

```
class myEvents {
public:
    //Variables
    int tSize = 40;
    int tileCount = 20;
    int width = tileCount * tSize;
    int height = tileCount * tSize;

    //Function to create a grid with RectangleShapes
    void grid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tileCount; j++) 
            {
                sf::RectangleShape tile(sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
                tile.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
                tile.setPosition(i*tSize, j*tSize);
                window.draw(tile); //Problem occurs here, 'window' is not declared, it is in the next function
                                    //window.draw(tile); must execute in the loop to render a full grid
            }
        }
    }

    //Includes while loop for rendering and events. Could be written without class, but I'd still like a class for the grid and later on a player.
    //So I need the window to work with my classes.
    void loop() {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Game"); //'window' declared here. Can I move this statement
                                                                        //somewhere so that my funcions know where it comes from?
        while (window.isOpen) {

            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(e))
            {
                //to be further developed
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You *can* create the `window` at some higher scope where all classes can access it, but I'd advise against it. If you have a lot of different places that try to draw into the same window tracking down bugs will be a huge pain. You should consider having a single class that is responsible for drawing (and that the other classes can call into) instead

Comment: Pass the window to your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well an easy thing for the window you can do is to create a class and 
add the window in it, then include the .h where the class is as you've set the sf::window in the public section. Now I will show you how you can use it

we've got an .h file named window.h (you can name it whatever is comfortable for you)

```
#include <SFML/Grpahics.hpp>
class window
{
public:
  sf::RenderWindow window;
}
```

and you have the main.cpp(or whatever file you want)

```
#include "window.h"
window w;

int main()
{
  w.window.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Title");
}
```

the int main() can be whatever function you want it just has to be
called as soon as possible so the window will show.
I hope this helps you with your problem =)
[EDID]:
As the "sf::RenderWindow window" is public  every file that has the header with the public "sf::RenderWindow window" can use the window as it is not private. I think you know that but in any case to add it.

Comment: Okay, thanks! This cleared some things up for me, but will have to test it as I get home to the computer. Thanks!

Comment: I hope it's what you need =)

Answer (score 1):

Try making the window a class member:

```
class myEvents {
public:
    //Variables
    int tSize = 40;
    int tileCount = 20;
    int width = tileCount * tSize;
    int height = tileCount * tSize;
    sf::RenderWindow window{sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Game"};

    void grid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tileCount; j++) 
            {
                sf::RectangleShape tile(sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
                tile.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
                tile.setPosition(i*tSize, j*tSize);
                window.draw(tile); 
            }
        }
    }

    void loop() {
        while (window.isOpen) {

            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(e))
            {
                //to be further developed
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, pass the window around:

```
class myEvents {
public:
    //Variables
    int tSize = 40;
    int tileCount = 20;
    int width = tileCount * tSize;
    int height = tileCount * tSize;

    void grid(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tileCount; j++) 
            {
                sf::RectangleShape tile(sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
                tile.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
                tile.setPosition(i*tSize, j*tSize);
                window.draw(tile); 
            }
        }
    }

    void loop() {
        sf::RenderWindow window{sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Game"};

        while (window.isOpen) {

            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(e))
            {
                //to be further developed
                // call grid(window)
            }
        }
    }
};
```